# jquery - how to get a image list from hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a construction:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="img01.jpg"><img src="img_s01.jpg"></a></li>
 <li><a href="img02.jpg"><img src="img_s02.jpg"></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

after click on any *a* i want to get a list:

```
<div>
<img src="img01.jpg">
<img src="img02.jpg">
...
</div>
```

what code i need on jquery?

not replace ul, just add new div after

this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/28eue/

Comment: What language?  What have you tried?

Comment: Should the list be in a separate `div` element?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var $replacement = $('<div>')

  $('a img').each(function() {
    $replacement.append($(this))
  })

  $('ul').replaceWith($replacement)
})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sqz2t/

You basically observe clicks on `a` tags and put all images into a freshly created div.

The code will replace the image list with the new div construction.

Comment: don't forget the end of <div> :-)

Comment: @ioan: you don't need to end it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to replace the existing `ul` element with a new `div` you can do this:

```
$("ul").replaceWith($("<div />").append($("ul img")));
```

...within a click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul").replaceWith($("<div />").append($("ul img")));
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k8N5M/

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler:

```
var newDiv = $('<div></div>');
$('ul li a').each(function(i, elem) {
    newDiv.append($('<img src="' + elem.href + '"'));
});
```

`newDiv` can then be inserted in the DOM, replacing the old list if that's what you want, or added to the page somewhere else.